# I can not select an item in dropdown Select2?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 Loading Remote Data with ajax. I get data in dropdown list, but I can not select it. How can I select, I have tried with ID, but it doesn't work, for ID i tried with obj, and data, but no luck. What am i doing wrong?!

Here is my code

if you need information please ask me

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Answer (score -1):

Check the code for code behind procedures.

**C#**

```
string sBook = "";
for (i = 0; i <= Books.Items.Count - 1; i++) {
    if (Books.Items(i).Selected) {
        sBook = Books.Items(i).Value;
    }
}
```

**Vb.Net**

```
Dim sBook As String = ""
For i = 0 To Books.Items.Count - 1
    If Books.Items(i).Selected Then
        sBook = Books.Items(i).Value
    End If
Next i
```

You can [check this article](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/07/multiple-selection-using-select2-jquery.htm) and find out if its useful.